# ckeditor image plugin customization

Tags: image, plugins, ckeditor

I want to customize the ckeditor image plugin. I already added two radio boxes under URL text field, one is the normal mode while for the second one I have shown a page in iframe in the preview area. In the page we have list of image links. Now I have difficulty to click on any link and send that link to the URL text field. Actually I want to access the URL field in the page shown in the iframe.

Please help me for it, or suggest me a better solution to tackle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do the above job. 
First I changed the radio boxes into brows button. On the button click event a light box opens. When clicking in a link in the light box the link value will be saved to java script COOKIE variable and on the light box close event the value from the COOKIE is retrieved and assigned to the text field with the following code.

```
srcVal = getCookie('srcVal');                                   dialog.setValueOf('info','src',srcVal);
```